# Prevent Folders from Appearing In Start Search Menu Results

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search, cortana

I'm trying to disable searching for folders in my Start menu search. I don't want any folders to show up. I only use Start when searching for applications or files and often find the first result is a folder and not the file I'm looking for. My file is on the list, just farther down.

Comment: You may try to disable search indexing service and delete all the search index and icon cache.

Comment: Please only make substantial edits to your question.  “Bumping” your question will result in an answer.

Comment: Please read [*What should I do if no one answers my question?*](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers) and stop making unsubstantial edits.

Comment: I can't offer a bounty since I'm so new here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any straightforward way to change the default behavior of the Windows search function to always exclude folders from results, but you should be able to use [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx) to accomplish the same goal.

The type: parameter can be used to search for files of a specific type. To find all folders that have MUSIC in the name, you'd search for

```
MUSIC type:folder
```

To exclude something from a search, you put a - in front of it. So combining these together, to search for all files with MUSIC in the name but exclude any folders, enter this:

```
  MUSIC -type:folder
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Where should I put this though? I understand the concept of AQS and how to use it when searching for files using Windows Explorer, but what should I do concerning Windows Start Search as a whole?